# Axios Multer is throwing Unexpected field error

Tags: node.js, axios, multer

So i've tested my route itself with postman and get the following if I `console.log(req.file)` I get the following:

```
{ fieldname: 'myImage',
originalname: '7yFHYXe.jpg',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff e2 0c 58 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 0c 48 4c 69 6e 6f 02 10 00 00 ... >,
size: 4760663 }
```

Which I believe is correct. Now if I test my axios request I get the `MulterError: Unexpected field`. Here is my axios code

```
...
export const addPostPicture = uploadData => dispatch => {
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("image", uploadData);
  console.log(data.get("image"));
  axios
    .post("/api/uploads/", data, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data`
      }
    })
...
```

When I `console.log(data.get("image"));` I get the following:
[image]

Forgive my ignorance this is my first time using multer. So any suggestions or feedback is great! =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like all the others with the same error I was dumb and didn't use the input name field accordingly...

So changing `data.append("myImage", uploadData);` fixed my problem.